# шорт код switch

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте
как правильнее написать такой код

```
<?php switch($index) : ?>
<?php case '1' : ?>
    <div><?= $index+1; ?></div>
    <?php break; ?>
<?php case '2' : ?>
    <div><?= $index+10; ?></div>
    <?php break; ?>
<?php default : ?>
    <div><?= $index+100; ?></div>
<?php endswitch; ?>
```

не удобно так писать

```
<?php switch($index) {
case '1' : echo '<div>'.$index+1.'</div>';
break;
case '2' : echo '<div>'.$index+10.'</div>';
break;
default : echo '<div>'.$index+1.'</div>';
```

}

потому что в коде html, надо много чего написать и html и php. с конкатами будет трудно разбираться.
Написал такой вариант но думаю это плохой.

```
<?php switch($index) {
case '1' : if(true) : ?>
    <div><?= $index+1; ?></div>
    <?php break; ?>
    <? endif; 
case '2' : if(true) : ?>
    <div><?= $index+10; ?></div>
    <?php break; ?>
    <? endif; 
default : if(true) : ?>
    <div><?= $index+100; ?></div>
    <? endif; 
} ?>
```

подскажите пожалуйста как лучше.

Comment: бгг. по моему в любом выводе html прямыми средствами пхп трудно разбираться. юзайте шаблонизаторы.

Comment: и в чем тайным смысл `if(true)` писать?

Comment: что бы я смог поставить двоеточии и закрыть php, по синтаксису 
<? if() : ?> . Без этого я не могу закрыть php в switch-е

Comment: не понял, в чем проблема. все вроде работает http://ideone.com/o0uRd8

Comment: Спасибо, так работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо.
Вариант такой:

```
<? $index=2;
switch($index) : ?>
<? case '1' : ?> <div><?= $index+1; ?></div>
<? break; ?>
<? case '2' : ?> <div><?= $index+10; ?></div>
<? break; ?>
<? default : ?> <div><?= $index+100; ?></div>
<?php endswitch; ?>
```